# Shuffle a small list in Redis DB

Tags: python, redis

i need to shuffle a small list (100 elements) in my Redis DB with Python.

Or is it easier to do the shuffling locally and then save it to the DB?

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how you think we can know what's easier for you without knowing your skill-set or your constraints. It's quite easy to get a list from Redis, shuffle it and put it back with Python. It's also easy to shuffle a list you have locally and put the result in Redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Redis list command to shuffle the order, so you'll need to shuffle it using Python (likely you can use the `random.shuffle` method) and then store that shuffled list in Redis.